# Bypassing Vlookup in Excel for import operation on related Objects

Tags: data-loader

I have 'Visit' object related to Account using Vlookup relation.

I have 10 Accounts and 30 'Visit' records which are related 1-many.
While inserting related 'Visit' I need to populate AccountID. I know I need to do Vlookup in Excel before inserting.

But I dont want to do Vlookup in Excel.

I have common field both in 'Visit' and 'Account' object.
I need to Vlookup using that common field

Is there any other way so that I can insert with Account__c field in 'Visit' using Dataloader

Comment: How is the excel file being populated? If it's via an external system, perhaps you have an external account id? I believe you can use that to load the Visit records. More information [here](http://blog.ryansieve.com/2013/03/14/using-salesforce-com-data-loader-upsert-with-an-external-id/).

Comment: Excel file is in CSV format where I need to populate Vlookup value of Account ID based on common field

Comment: I don't see any other way to do what you are asking for if there is no other id except for the salesforce account id.  The vlookup should pretty straightforward no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make the 'common' field an external Id on the Account field definition
2. upsert the Visit records via DataLoader (make sure to use Upsert and not Insert).
3. Dataloader will ask you if you want to use any external Id to link Visit to Account.
4. Select the newly created external id, and link the 'common' field on Visit to that field on Account
5. Complete the Upsert. The Visits will be linked to the Accounts without account Id's being required.